# Yii2 validate field not containing xxxx

Tags: php, yii2

I need to validate a field to confirm that It doesnt contain an URL. Is It possible to set a rule within the model like [['field'], '!Url']? Or any other approach

Thanks

Comment: you want to allow only characters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
 ['field', 'match', 'pattern' => '/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)/i', 'not'=>true]
```

Regex will match urls like

- www.google.com
- http://www.google.com
- mailto:somebody@google.com
- somebody@google.com
- www.url-with-querystring.com/?url=has-querystring

[Regex example](https://regex101.com/r/cX0pJ8/1)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the match rule for this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#match

And you may create a regex to define all the allowed characters, for example:

```
['field', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/']
```